# Flutter VSCode failed to run on a real device

Tags: android, flutter, visual-studio-code

I want to run my flutter project on visual studio code with a real device (no emulator) since my laptop have a limited ram.

When I want to run it showing error after downloading.

I tied flutter doctor and eveything is ok and also I have enable us debugging on my android.

[image]

Comment: try this command -- flutter pub upgrade

Answer (score 0):

just plug in your device via USB and run

```
flutter run -d $deviceName
```